# Image extension validation using javascript

Tags: javascript

here is my java script code which i am using for validating image extension:

```
if (allTrim(document.ff.myfile.value) != ""){      
var asc=document.ff.myfile.value;
var le=asc.length;
var poin=asc.lastIndexOf(".");
var accu1=asc.substring(poin,le);
var accu = accu1.toLowerCase(); 
alert(accu) ;
if ((accu !='.png') || (accu !='.jpg')){
  alert ("Please Select Valid Image");
  return false;
}}
```

alltrim() is my custom function which trims of any symbol or anything. 
when i input jpeg file it's working fine. but when i input png it's says please select valid image

Comment: It is the || in your IF statement  '((accu !='.png') || (accu !='.jpg'))' it should be an AND '((accu !='.png') && (accu !='.jpg'))'

Comment: @dorinaji thanx it 's working now...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a problem with your if statement. Use this code:

```
var asc="imasdsadas//his/jjpp.mp4";
var le=asc.length;
var poin=asc.lastIndexOf(".");
var accu1=asc.substring(poin,le);
var accu = accu1.toLowerCase(); 
console.log(accu);
//alert(accu) ;
if ((accu !='.png') && (accu !='.jpg')){
  console.log ("Please Select Valid Image");
}else{console.log("valid image");}
```

Comment: thanx now i get it

Answer (score 0):

In your condition block you have:

```
if ((accu !='.png') || (accu !='.jpg')){
  alert ("Please Select Valid Image");
  return false;
}}
```

which will be `true` in all cases (can an extension be `.jpg` and `.png` at the same time?). You can replace it with and instead of or, which give `true` if `accu` don't satisfy both condition.

Answer (score 0):

We can easily take extension and check it with array of extensions, we only need to add mode extensions to the array, no need for irritating `if` loops. Check the snippet, hope this is what you looking for..

What i have done here is,

1. take the file extension on `input change event`,
2. split it, take the part after '/' and match it with the array.
3. if the result is `-1` then, the extension is not in the list and is invalid

```js
function fileChange(e){
  var ext = event.target.files[0].type.split('/')[1];
  var extArray = ['png', 'jpeg']
  if(extArray.indexOf(ext) == -1){
    alert("Please Select Valid Image");
    event.target.value = '';
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="file" id="file" onChange="fileChange()"/>
```